# How to make CSS animated background scrolling?

Tags: css

I saw an example of CSS animation for background scrolling at http://www.pandarisk.com/ and now I am wondering how to achieve it? Is there any tutorial with demo to understand it?

Comment: it's a webpage. you downloaded all of the relevant code when you viewed it. "view source" and start reading.

Answer (score 0):

This type of animation is called parallax scrolling. Here is a tutorial with an explanation how to achieve this: https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh sorry, you misunderstood it. Actually I was referring to animated background at the bottom of page which has fixed position and scrolls from right to left.